# Numpy Vectorization: add row above to current row on ndarray

Tags: numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I would like to add the values in the above row to the row below using vectorization. For example, if I had the ndarray,

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [2, 2, 2, 2],
 [3, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Then after one iteration through this method, it would result in

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [3, 3, 3, 3],
 [5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

One can simply do this with a for loop:

```
import numpy as np

def addAboveRow(arr):
    cpy = arr.copy()

    r, c = arr.shape
    for i in range(1, r):
        for j in range(c):
            cpy[i][j] += arr[i - 1][j]

    return cpy

ndarr = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]).reshape(4, 4)
print(addAboveRow(ndarr))
```

I'm not sure how to approach this using vectorization though. I think slicers should be used? Also, I'm not really sure how to deal with the issue of the top border, because nothing should be added onto the first row. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Note: I am really new to vectorization so an explanation would be great!

Comment: You could create a second array with a zero top row and all further rows just like the first to last but one row of the original array and then add it to the first array. If it fits into memory that should be fast enough.

Comment: That works. I am just wondering if there is a more "numpythonic" way to approach that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexing directly:

```
b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[0] = a[0]
b[1:] = a[1:] + a[:-1]
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [5, 5, 5, 5]])
```

An alternative:

```
b = a.copy()
b[1:] += a[:-1]
```

Or:

```
b = a.copy()
np.add(b[1:], a[:-1], out=b[1:])
```

Comment: Why does the alternative solution work? I am a little confused on that, because b[1:] would be every single row after the first, but we are adding the last row because a[:-1]?

Comment: We are adding everything up to and excluding the last row. Try printing a[:-1] separately, exactly the same addition as in the first example.

Comment: Ah. I see now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```py
np.put(arr, np.arange(arr.shape[1], arr.size), arr[1:]+arr[:-1])
```